# I want to extract names of user according to profile Id or Name

Tags: soql

I want to extract names of user using specific ProfileId or Name.

How to do this??

Answer (score 1):

In Case of user extract use the below query :

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM User WHERE ProfileId = '00e61000000W75v' AND IsActive = True
```

At apex class you can use the either of the below 2:-

If the Id of the profile is known to you :-

```
List<User> lstUsr = [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE ProfileId = '00e61000000W75v' AND IsActive = True];
System.debug('@@@ '+lstUsr);
```

Or you if the have the name of the profile :

```
Profile pf = [Select Id from Profile where Name = 'BU/Sales Operations'];
List<User> lstUsr = [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE ProfileId =: pf.Id AND IsActive = True];
System.debug('@@@ '+lstUsr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the data loader tool or dataloader.io which is a web tool to extract the User records. While extracting you can modify your query as below. Please make sure to have your field names, and profile name appropriately. Below is a screenshot from dataloader.io screens.

```
SELECT Id, IsActive, CompanyName, Username FROM User Where Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's a relatively easy process, and you can even Automate it.
Check out [this link](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/automate-salesforce-data-import-export-using-data-loader-cli) containing detailed step by step code process to implement DataLoader.

Let me know if it was helpful.

--Updated the URL above--